# Can I replace substrings in a formula stored in a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to replace values within a formula stored as a string in SQL.

Example formulas stored in a column:

'=AA+BB/DC'

'=-(AA+CC)'

'=AA/BB+DD'

I have values for AA, BB etc. stored in another table.

**Can I find and replace 'AA', 'BB' and so forth from within the formulas with numeric values to actually calculate the formula?**

I assume I also need to replace the arithmetic operators ('+' , '/') from strings to actual signs, and if so is there a way to do it?

**Desired Result**

**Assuming: AA = 10, BB = 20, DC = 5**

I would need

'=AA+BB/DC' converted to 10+20/5 and a final output of 14

Please note that formulas can change in the future so I would need something resilient to that.

Thank you!

Comment: No easily.  You would need to use dynamic SQL for this.  Or perhaps you might have your own custom-built function.

Comment: Whenever I see requirements like this, it always seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). SQL isn't a scripting language, you can't do something like `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('(AA + BB) / CC)','AA', 10),'BB',12),'CC',2);` and expect it to return `11`; it's going to return the `varchar` value `'(10 + 12) / 2'`. `(n)varchar`s aren't parsed as expressions; they're just strings.

Comment: Does the calculation *absolutely, positively, no other way* have to be done within the database, or could you just return the expression and the required values to the calling application and use an ordinary programming language to parse and evaluate?

Comment: There are two options: 1.Create a function to each formula you want
2. Use dynamic SQL. This may be less performant

Comment: @larnu actually its possible with dynamic SQL. There's a way achieve the "parsing" aka `eval()`  of the formulas with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but those formulas should be adapted in order to make them correct arithmetical expressions (thus removing the `=`). Coupled with the replacement of all variables, all that would definitively require a procedure.

Comment: @ThomasG I am well aware of Dynamic SQL, however, that doesn't change my point. A literal string is still a literal string, and SQL isn't a scripting language. Trying to treat it like one is rarely a good idea. Trying to achieve something like it opens up a lot of considerations to ensure you take into account; must importantly making sure that the injection in secure to avoid injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is a **real** hack, but I was intrigued by your question. You could turn my example into a function and then refactor it to your specific needs.

**Note**: using `TRANSLATE` requires **SQL Server 2017**. This could be a deal-breaker for you right there. `TRANSLATE` simplifies the replacement process greatly.

This example is just that--an example. A hack. Performance issues are unknown. You still need to do your diligence with testing.

```
-- Create a mock-up of the values table/data.
DECLARE @Values TABLE ( [key] VARCHAR(2), [val] INT );
INSERT INTO @Values ( [key], [val] ) VALUES 
    ( 'AA', 10 ), ( 'BB', 20 ), ( 'CC', 6 ), ( 'DC', 5 );

-- Variable passed in to function.
DECLARE @formula VARCHAR(255) = '=(AA+BB)/DC';

-- Remove unnecessary mathmatical characters from the formula values.
DECLARE @vals VARCHAR(255) = REPLACE ( TRANSLATE ( @formula, '=()', '___' ), '_', '' );

-- Remove any leading mathmatical operations from @vals.
WHILE PATINDEX ( '[A-Z]', LEFT ( @vals, 1 ) ) = 0
    SET @vals = SUBSTRING ( @vals, 2, LEN ( @vals ) );

-- Use SQL hack to replace placeholder values with actual values...
SELECT @formula = REPLACE ( @formula, fx.key_val, v.val )
FROM (
    
    SELECT 
        [value] AS [key_val],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS [key_id] 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT ( TRANSLATE ( @vals, '+/*-', ',,,,' ), ',' )
    
) AS fx
INNER JOIN @Values v
    ON Fx.[key_val] = v.[key]
ORDER BY
    fx.[key_id]

-- Return updated formula.
SELECT @formula AS RevisedFormula;

-- Return the result (remove the equals sign).
SET @formula = FORMATMESSAGE ( 'SELECT %s AS FormulaResult;', REPLACE ( @formula, '=', '' ) );
EXEC ( @formula );
```

`SELECT @formula AS RevisedFormula;` returns:

```
+----------------+
| RevisedFormula |
+----------------+
| =(10+20)/5     |
+----------------+
```

The last part of my example uses `EXEC` to do the math. **You cannot use EXEC in a function.**

```
-- Return the result (remove the equals sign).
SET @formula = FORMATMESSAGE ( 'SELECT %s AS FormulaResult;', REPLACE ( @formula, '=', '' ) );
EXEC ( @formula );
```

Returns

```
+---------------+
| FormulaResult |
+---------------+
|             6 |
+---------------+
```

Changing the formula value to `=-(AA+CC)` returns:

```
+----------------+
| RevisedFormula |
+----------------+
| =-(10+6)       |
+----------------+

+---------------+
| FormulaResult |
+---------------+
|           -16 |
+---------------+
```

It's probably worth noting to pay attention to math order in your formulas. Your original example of `=AA+BB/DC` returns **14**, not the **6** that may have been expected. I updated your formula to `=(AA+BB)/DC` for my example.